# Composer update error when updating laravel 6 -> 8

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to update my Laravel version from 6 -> 8 by following this guide https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade

I'm not sure if I should update to Laravel 7 first, then to 8, never the less, I face the same composer problem when trying to update to 7.

composer update output:

```
        Problem 1
        - illuminate/database 5.7.17 requires illuminate/support 5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.7.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
        - illuminate/database v5.4.9 requires nesbot/carbon ~1.20 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.20.0, 1.21.0, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.23.0, 1.24.0, 1.24.1, 1.24.2, 1.25.0, 1.25.1, 1.25.3, 1.26.0, 
    1.26.1, 1.26.2, 1.26.3, 1.26.4, 1.26.5, 1.26.6, 1.27.0, 1.28.0, 1.29.0, 1.29.1, 1.29.2, 1.30.0, 1.31.0, 1.31.1, 1.32.0, 1.33.0, 1.34.0, 1.34.1, 1.34.2, 1.34.3, 1.34.4, 1.35.0, 1.35.1, 1.36.0, 1.36.1, 1.36.2, 1.37.0, 1.37.1, 1.38.0, 1.38.1, 1.38.2, 1.38.3, 1.38.4, 1.39.0, 1.39.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.28.4
     - Installation request for roave/security-advisories dev-master -> satisfiable by roave/security-advisories[dev-master].
      - silber/bouncer v1.0.0-rc.6 requires illuminate/database 5.1.20 - 5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.7.0, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 
5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev], illuminate/database[5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, 
v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.36, v6.18.37, v6.18.38, v6.18.39, v6.18.4, v6.18.40, v6.18.41, v6.18.42, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
 - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev].
 - don't install illuminate/database 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
 - Installation request for laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.28.0, v7.28.1, v7.28.2, v7.28.3, v7.28.4, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - Installation request for silber/bouncer v1.0.0-rc.6 -> satisfiable by silber/bouncer[v1.0.0-rc.6].
```

composer.json require:

```
    "require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-pdo": "*",
    "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "^2.17",
    "doctrine/dbal": "2.9.3",
    "felixkiss/uniquewith-validator": "^3.1",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.2",
    "lab404/laravel-impersonate": "^1.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/helpers": "^1.1",
    "laravel/passport": "^8.0.1",
    "laravel/socialite": "^4.3",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.0.3",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
    "league/flysystem-cached-adapter": "^1.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "moontoast/math": "^1.2",
    "mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator": "^3.10",
    "mpociot/laravel-test-factory-helper": "^1.2",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^2.27",
    "nicolaslopezj/searchable": "^1.12",
    "pdfcrowd/pdfcrowd": "^4.3",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "ramsey/uuid-doctrine": "^1.6",
    "silber/bouncer": "v1.0.0-rc.6",
    "socialiteproviders/apple": "^3.0",
    "spatie/geocoder": "^3.6",
    "spatie/laravel-json-api-paginate": "^1.6",
    "spatie/laravel-sitemap": "^5.7",
    "twilio/sdk": "^5.18",
    "vimeo/vimeo-api": "^3.0",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.7"
},
"require-dev": {
    "roave/security-advisories": "dev-master",
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.2",
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "ajthinking/tinx": "^2.1",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5",
    "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
},
```

Comment: check doc it's `Upgrading To 8.0 From 7.x` you cannot update from 6 to 8 you may break something so better to update 6 to 7 1st then 7 to 8

Comment: and one more you are using `vimeo/laravel` which does not have support for `laravel 8` https://github.com/vimeo/laravel/issues/79

Comment: Error message is clear: `vimeo/laravel dev-master requires illuminate/support ^5.8|^6.0|^7.0` so either remove this package or wait for the `v8` support.

Comment: I've removed vimeo/laravel now, and I'm also updating to Laravel 7 instead of Laravel 8.

I've updated the response and composer.json require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one of the packages you're using doesn't support Laravel 7 or 8. The composer error message tells you which one.

According to the error message, `"silber/bouncer": "v1.0.0-rc.6"` only supports up to Laravel 6. Looking at the composer.json for that package shows that support for Laravel 7 wasn't added until `v1.0.0-rc.7`, and support for Laravel 8 wasn't added until `v1.0.0-rc.9`.

You'll need to update your `silber/bouncer` dependency and then try again. If you run into another error, you'll need to look at the message to determine which package doesn't meet the requirements, and then figure out what version of that package you need to get to in order to meet the requirements.

Since Laravel 8 is fairly new, you may run into some packages that haven't been updated to support it yet (such as `vimeo/laravel`). In that case, you'll either need to wait until those packages support it, or fork the package and attempt to add the support yourself.

Answer (score 0):

#1 - Make sure the composer.json looks like this

```
"require": {
   "php": "^7.2",
   "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
   "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
   "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
   "laravel/socialite": "^5.0",
   "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
   "laravel/ui": "^3.0",
   "predis/predis": "^1.1"
},
"require-dev": {
   "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
   "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
   "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
   "phpunit/phpunit": "^9"
}
```

#2 -  if you see following issue

> laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.

Remove remove **illuminate/support**

`composer remove illuminate/support`

#3 - The report, render, shouldReport, and renderForConsole methods of your application's App\Exceptions\Handler class should accept instances of the Throwable interface instead of Exception instances:
Change **app/Exceptions/Handler.php** as follow

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Throwable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
   /**
    * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $dontReport = [
       //
   ];

   /**
    * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $dontFlash = [
       'password',
       'password_confirmation',
   ];

   /**
    * Report or log an exception.
    *
    * @param  \Throwable  $exception
    * @return void
    */
   public function report(Throwable $exception)
   {
       parent::report($exception);
   }

   /**
    * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Throwable  $exception
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
   public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
   {
       return parent::render($request, $exception);
   }
}
```